# Port intent-filter from Android to Blackberry

Tags: android, porting, blackberry-10, intentfilter

I am porting my Android app to BlackBerry Playbook.

My app using intent-filter like that:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>

<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

But it's doesn't work on BlackBerry

How can i fix it?

Thanks you

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. From what I can tell, BlackBerry 10 doesn't support intent-filters. Their unsupported API documentation doesn't mentiont his, however.